# How can I encode and decode a circular JSON object with circular pointers?

Tags: javascript, json, circular-reference

I want to encode and decode a circular JSON object with circular pointers.

**It's not duplicate because I want to encode with circular and decode it. I need circulars objects after decode!**

This is just a simple object but I have a complicated object.

```js
var obj = {
  parent1: {
     child1: {}
  }
};

obj.parent1.child1.parent = obj.parent1;

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // ERROR: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

I try to change pointers to address like:

```
obj.parent1.child1.parent = '$P$root.parent1$';
```

and when decode correct it.

**But how can I detect which object is a pointer. And how can i get object address?**

Comment: For parsing back to an object, you'll want to use a _reviver_ function in [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Syntax) to restore whatever reference you used during serialisation. If that's not possible, you'll have to iterate through the parsed object and replace references

Comment: @Phil How can I detect which object is a pointer when serialize it. And how can i get pointer address?

Comment: @Phil Is this question duplicate? And why?

Comment: Yes, it is. Did you have a look at some of the answers? Many offer examples and links showing encoding **and** decoding options.

Comment: I found it. Thanks a lot. I thought after the answer with -11 vote is badder and don't look they.